# Is there a way to automate p4win to submit a changelist and re-open the same files in a changelist with same description?

Tags: perforce, p4win

If I want to create a checkpoint in my work, I often find myself submitting a chunk of files, only to re-open the same files again and continue working on them. Repeat this for several sets of files, many times over. Has anyone had to automate this? I am looking for a custom tool in p4win, or an autohotkey script tied to a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

p4win is rather out-dated. p4v has an option to reopen files after you submit them: "Check out submitted files after submit"

Comment: p4win also has that option. But does p4v put them in a CL with the same description, or does it keep them in a default CL ?